# Passing parameters between C# and Labview with ActiveX

Tags: c#, com, activex, labview

I've two questions:

I would like to know what sort of variable types can I pass into labview from C# or python, using activeX. 
I guess they would be things like, number types, strings, etc. But what about paths, or error clusters?

Also in labview I normally pass in labview objects into my subvi's. How would it be possible to do this from another language?

Lets say I have a self defined database object that I normally pass around in labview. Can I call some factory method vi from C#, and get the control from the front panel after running the vi. Cast that as a generic object in C#, and then call another vi, and pass in the object?

Like.

```
// Get a vi reference, and run my databaseFactory vi.
string databaseFactoryPath = ...;  
VirtualInstrument viTest = labVIEWApp.GetVIReference(databaseFactoryPath "", false, 0);
databaseFactoryVi.Run(true);

// Get the database labview object from the frontpanel control called "database out"
object databaseObject = (object)viTest.GetControlValue("database out");

// Obtain a reference to a database method called load.vi
string databaseLoadPath = ...;
VirtualInstrument databaseload = labVIEWApp.GetVIReference(databaseLoadPath "", false, 0);

string parameterName = "database in";
databaseLoad.Call( parameterName, databaseObject );
```

...

This doesn't work because an exception is thrown at viTest.GetControlValue("database out"):
"The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Anyone know if it is possible to do such things?
(I'm trying to get out of labview programming, but I don't want to render all my code as useless in the process.)

Thanks, 
labjunky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LabVIEW has an option to generate a .NET assembly itself that wraps your VIs and is callable from your .NET application. I think, this is one of the options that's often neglected by G developers when trying to use G code in .NET apps.This is the "*.NET Interop Assembly*" option in your BuildSpecification in the LV Project.

You can select the VIs from your project that you want to be exposed for calling in your .NET application (I think, it can generate for LVOOP vis also); generate the .NET wrapper assembly; and then use this wrapper assembly to interface with the LabVIEW code from your .NET app.

Of course, if the types are basic, then while selecting the VIs, it automatically configures the function signature. I'm not sure, if the references/handles can be passed around seamlessly between the .NET/LabVIEW boundary. But, I'm sure its faster for you to write a integer/string-to-LVObject-map in LabVIEW side, and then use the common type to refer to them across the boundaries, than to re-write all the code in a .NET language.

Comment: Thanks mherle, in principle this is the solution. Having read the documentation on this, labview will convert labview classes into .net classes, and you can pass these instances into the .net assembly you make from labview. However, I'm using labview 2009, and I can't get it to build an assembly, because the build assistant fails every time with an .net exception during the build process. Error 1157. No idea why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of questions to answer...I'll go for a few general answers to all of them.

LabVIEW supports .NET 4.0 as of LabVIEW 2010.  Versions older than that generally support .NET 3.5.  You can call .NET code and use .NET objects from within LabVIEW using Constructor nodes, Property Nodes, and Invoke Nodes.  Search the palettes for .NET and you'll find some good support.

LabVIEW's support for passing data out is somewhat limited.  Passing LabVIEW objects (classes) out is hard (if not impossible.  I work on the LabVIEW team and I'm not sure...mostly because I've never tried it).  You can flatten most other types to strings (better described as an array of u8s that we treat as a string) and pass the resulting string to .NET or a native DLL.  You can read about the [flattened data format](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvconcepts/flattened_data/) here.

You should definitely check out [Measurement Studio](http://www.ni.com/mstudio/).  They have some awesome tools for creating LabVIEW-like controls in .NET.  You might also be interested in LabWindows (I'd link it, but SO won't let me since I'm a relatively new user).  I know it looks like I'm just trying to sell more NI products, but honestly these may be viable solutions for what you're trying to do.

There's no public way to call a VI from .NET code (last time I checked.  It's been 3 years since I worked on Measurement Studio, the most likely product to help you call VIs from .NET).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. So basically if you use labview classes you can't call your routines from any other language. That's quite a limitation! If I were to flatten the objects to strings then I would have to modify a lot of code. Also using dynamic dispatch would be difficult. (An alternative would be to create a DLL. I have tried making a DLL from labview, but you can only use C types in those.) I wish I had known that when I started using labview! Is there no way to pass the data out as a variant?